# reading multiple choice questions and answers from file python

Tags: python, file, file-handling

hi all im having trouble trying to set up a quiz which reads questions and answers from file, i am a python beginner, i have already set up the code but i am having trouble getting it to display the question in the correct format from file, each line is not in a order i would like, below is the code i have so far and also the layout of my text file

code:

```
import sys

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", e)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file


def next_line(the_file):
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line 

def next_block(the_file):

    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]

    return question, answers, correct

def welcome(title):
    print("\t\tWelcome to who wants to be a millionaire quiz\n")
    print("\t\t", title, "\n")

def main():
    question_file = open_file("questions.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(question_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

# get first block
    question, answers, correct = next_block(question_file)

    for i in range(3):
            print("\t", i + 1, answers[i])

        # get answer
    answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        # check answer
    if answer == correct:
        print("\nRight!", end=" ")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        question, answers, correct = next_block(question_file)

        question_file.close()

        print("That was the last question!")
        print("You're final score is", score)

main()  
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

and this is the layout of the text file:
Complete the title of the James Bond film The Man With The Golden.  question
face answer 1 
hand answer 2 
eye  answer 3
gun answer 4
2 correct answer
In which sport do two teams pull at the opposite ends of a rope
tennis
football
hockey
tug of war
3

Comment: sorry the text file layout is Complete the title of the James Bond film The Man With The Golden.  question
<face< answer 1
<hand> answer 2 
<eye>  answer 3
<gun> answer 4                                                  <2>correct answer

Comment: In what format do you want to display the quiz?

Comment: Multiple choice with the question and 4 answers